# How to specify a default path for a File Target when a given event-property is not present?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, nlog-configuration

I have a `File Target` as follow:

```
<target xsi:type="File" 
        name="f" 
        fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${event-properties:EmployeeID}.log" 
        ... 
/>
```

This file target logs the entries of each employee in a separate file based on the `EmployeeID` value, but some log entries don't have this `EmployeeID` property. How to log these entries to a default path ?

Is there syntax like this ?

```
fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${event-properties:EmployeeID || 'UnknownEmployee'}.log"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to make use of the ambient layoutrenderer `whenEmpty`.

Example:

```
fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${event-properties:EmployeeID:whenEmpty=UnknownEmployee}.log"
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/WhenEmpty-Layout-Renderer